# Handover execution to main thread in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am using Runnable to do some background task in my android application. The runnable after completing the background task will call a callback which is implemented by caller of the function which implemented runnable. Now i want to handover execution to main thread once the callback is called.

```
public void DoInBackground(Callback callback)
{
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
//Execution that to be done in background
//calling callback once the result is obtained
});
thread.start()
}

public void callee(){
DoInBackground(new callback(){
@Override
public void onSuccess(int value){
//Do operations after completion of background task
}
});
}
```

I want the onSucess to run on the main thread rather than the new runnable created in DoInBackground function.
I know it can be done with async task. Is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use an `Handler` to `post` a runnable in the UI Thread queue, or if the context is the Activity ones you can use the `runOnUiThread` method. The snippet inside the runnable will be run on the UI Thread

Answer (score 0):

put your callback function inside runOnUiThread function :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // callback function

            }
        });
```